# How to assign or reference an API's value to the HTML <option> value Attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Here's the sitRep:

I've got a 2 drop down  menus with several selections each, and the selections *("option:selected" in js)* are meant to be query parameters that are connected to an API fetch in my javascript file.

I need to set the ***value=""*** within the ***option*** on the HTML file to reflect its designation/location in the API, and I've had no luck in discovering the proper syntax.

For clarity, here's a snippet of the html in question:

```
 <select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="platform-drop" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
                            <option selected>Platforms:</option>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="playstation-5">Playstation 5</option>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="playstation-4">Playstation 4</option>
                            <option class="dropdown-item" value="xbox-series">XBOX Series X/S</option>
```

So, everywhere within  that reads *<value="xbox-series">* or any other platform needs to instead read something akin to

```
<option class="dropdown-item" value="apiSource.platforms.id:187">XBOX Series X/S</option>
```

as the api identifies the XBOX SERIES X/S, in this case, as *->Platform->"id": 187*. And that's where I get lost in the woods.

An "under-construction" jS for reference and for anyone wondering why I don't just *innerHTML* or *textContent* to a ***div*** and be done with it:

```
var platformBtn = $('#platform-drop');
var genreBtn = $('#genre-drop');
var submitBtn = $('#submit-btn');

submitBtn.on('click', function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    var platformSelection = $("#platform-drop option:selected").val();
    console.log(platformSelection)
    var genreSelection = $('#genre-drop option:selected').val();
    console.log(genreSelection)
    
    var gamesUrl = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?genres="+genreSelection+"&platforms="+platformSelection+"&key=0da6d52b21ec4d8fac88f4f4ceafe806";

    fetch(gamesUrl)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        console.log(data.results);
    })
})
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

-LujanSolo

Answer (score 0):

After reading [rawg.io api documentation](https://api.rawg.io/docs/) I realized you are sending wrong information on your request here:

```
var gamesUrl = "https://api.rawg.io/api/games?genres="+genreSelection+"&platforms="+platformSelection+"&key=0da6d52b21ec4d8fac88f4f4ceafe806";
```

I don't know how you defined `genreSelection` but I assume u defined it correcly let's assume
`genreSelection = 'action';`

You should fill `platforms` with id or string of multiple id separating with , like this:

```
platforms = '2';
//in this case you will get games available for platform id 2 


platforms = '2,3,4'; 
//in this case you will get games available for 2 and 3 and 4 platform ids
```

So you should change your code to:

```
<select class="form-select form-select-lg mb-3 btn btn-secondary btn-lg" id="platform-drop" aria-label=".form-select-lg example">
  <option selected>Platforms:</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="187">Playstation 5</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="18">Playstation 4</option>
  <option class="dropdown-item" value="186">XBOX Series X/S</option>
</select>
```

You can also get list of platforms to see which platform is what id with a get request to:
`https://api.rawg.io/api/platforms?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

> replace <YOUR_API_KEY> with your api key

**You can also check [this DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-t82ffn?file=index.html)**

Comment: Great! You got me started along the right track. The <pre> was a solid call and I removed the option:selected from my javascript, which was causing me to read the original values...
Anyway, a laundry list of things followed, but it works now!  Thank you!

Comment: Oh, and I changed my API key after realizing I posted it to a monstrously huge public forum!

Comment: Happy to help, I advise you make your request on back-end, otherwise you will expose your api key if you use it on front-end using javascript.